# How can I make my SelectListItem overload set the “Value” property to be the same as the “Text” property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I’am tryinng to do something like this in my view:

```
 @{
     string selectgedOne = ViewBag.sellectedvalue;
 }

      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, Model.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString(), Selected = x.ToString().Equals(selectgedOne.ToString()) }))
```

But what returns is...

```
 System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
```

I’m sort of successful whin I use this version …

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, Model.Categories, selectgedOne)
```

…here it sets the value in the list box but when I F12 the page I see that first option value is not set to the same as the text…

```
  <select id="Category" name="Category">
  <option value="">Tests</option>
  <option value="In class participation">In class participation</option>
  <option value="Homework">Homework</option>
  <option value="Projects">Projects</option>
  <option value="Tests">Tests</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
```

… so if I post this to the controller Categary will be a empty string.

How can I make my SelectListItem overload set the “Value” property to be the same as the “Text” property?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent the value (assignCategory) that I want at the top of the list then...

```
  public ActionResult Categories(int? id, int? department, String assignCategory)
    {
        var categories = new List<SelectListItem>();               
        for (int i = 0; i < rubricsList.Count(); i++)
        {
            categories.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = rubricsList[i],
                Value = rubricsList[i],
                Selected = true
            });
        }
        switch (assignCategory)
        {
            case "A":
                categories.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = rubricsList[0],
                    Value = rubricsList[0],
                    Selected = true
                });
                break;
    // More cases here
 }
```

The return view is partial with a single line that looks like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category,  Model.Categories)
```

Now the first value in the dropdown list is set and can be submitted properly